# Confusion about $\Delta_{S^n} u(x) = \Delta u\bigg(\frac{x}{|x|}\bigg)$, why do we need to divide by $|x|$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $S$ be a sphere of radius 1. We know the formula
$$\Delta_S u(x) = \Delta u\bigg(\frac{x}{|x|}\bigg)$$
holds for a function $u:S \to \mathbb{R}$ where $\Delta_S$ is the Laplace-Beltrami and the $\Delta$ is the usual Laplacian.

I am a bit confused about this formula. We only really want to use $\Delta_S u(x)$ for points $x \in S$, in which case $|x|=1$, so why can't we just write
$$\Delta_S u(x) = \Delta u(x)?$$

Why bother with the division?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u$ is defined only on $S$ then $\Delta u$ doesn't make sense doesn't it?

We are not evaluating "$\Delta u$" at $x/|x|$, we are taking $\Delta$ of the function $u(x/|x|)$ (then plugging in).

Comment: I agree we are not evaluating it. So then is it right to set $|x|=1$ after taking $\Delta$ of $u(x/|x|)$? But not before?

Comment: @riem You pick an $x\in S$ to evaluate $\Delta(u(\frac{x}{|x|}))$ at, yes. So you understand why "$\Delta u(x)$," beyond not being correct for the formula, doesn't make any sense?

Comment: Hmm. I thought it was that to define $\Delta u(x)$ we need an extension of $u$ off $S$ to the ambient space beyond. I don't know what you mean by "not being correct for the formula" though.

Comment: And that extension to the ambient space is $u(\frac{x}{|x|})$, which is exactly why that shows up in the formula and not the original $u(x)$! By $\Delta u(x)$ not being correct for the formula I mean it is the wrong thing to put on the right-hand side of the formula $\Delta_Su(x)=\square$ (since it doesn't even make sense).